# Java string manipulation x number of lines with y element

Tags: java

Easiest way to explain my problem is to give you an example. Lets say I have 2 values X and Y. I wan't to ask the user to enter X lines with Y elements and they should be only 0s and 1s and then enter that values in array.

**Example**

```
x=3 y=3
User input:
101
100
000
```

And then how to separate string to enter each value in different cell.

EDIT 1:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedVsGreen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x,y;
        String line;
        String[] lineVector = new String[3];

 while ( lineVector.length !=2 || (Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]) >= 1000 || Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]) <= 1)
                ||  (Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]) <= 1 || Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]) >= 1000)){
            System.out.print("Please enter x and y, comma separated (more than 1 and less than 1000):");
            //read x,y
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            //separate all values by comma
            lineVector = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        }

        //parsing the values to Integer
        x = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);

        for (i = 0 ; i < x; i++){
            
        }
//
//            int[][] field = new int[x][y];
//            for (int row = 0; row < field.length; row++) {
//                System.out.println("");
//                for (int col = 0; col < field[row].length; col++) {
//                    field[row][col] = 9; //dummy value
//                    System.out.print(field[row][col] + " ");
//                }
//            }
//
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your attempts.

Comment: I have tried to use scanner with nextline, but I have the following problems. I don't know how to ensure that there is y elements, but for the lines I can do just simple for loop. Also I have triend to split the strings, but there is a mess. So I would say almost everthing goes wrong

Comment: @SimeonLazarov share your code and someone will be able to help you starting from there.

Comment: I have added edit 1 with a link to the code. I have done filling the array (I mean its working) Now I need only to get X lines with Y elements and replace the dummy value

Comment: Don't link to your code.  Links can break, or the file that they link to can change.  Both destroy the context for the question and render it and the answers meaningless.  Instead, *copy the relevant parts of the code into the Question*.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  I have shared all the code. Just to note in the empty for-loop I should scan for X lines with Y elements and then to fill the 2d array that I have commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Receiving x and y**

```
while ( lineVector.length !=2 ...)
```

Your while condition is too complicated, a do while format matches this problem much better since you are going to get the values at least once, and the code is more readable.

Also you could have used x instead of `Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0])` (same for y) instead of repeating the process, this would have shortened the condition.

```
String line;
String[] lineVector;
int x = -1, y = -1;

    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter x and y, comma separated (more than 1 and less than 1000):");

        line = scanner.nextLine();
        lineVector = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");

        if(lineVector.length != 2)
            continue;

        x = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[0]);
        y = Integer.parseInt(lineVector[1]);
    } while (!((x > 1 && x < 1000 && y > 1 && y < 1000)));
```

First of all I removed the initial value of `lineVector` as it is unnecessary to initialize it in this case (you needed to do it because of it being present in your while condition).

I initialized `x` and `y` to -1 (Any number not in our range would work) in order to make sure the do-while condition is fulfilled until proper values are offered for both of the numbers.

**Function to check binary values**

Create a function to check if string values are binary.

```
public static boolean isBinary(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c != '0' && c != '1')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Receive binaries**

```
String[] binaries = new String[x];

System.out.println("Enter binaries with length " + y + " :");

//Get binaries
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    binaries[i] = scanner.nextLine();

    while(!isBinary(binaries[i]) || binaries[i].length() != y) {
        System.out.println("Invalid binary value. Re-enter new value:");
        binaries[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Receive binary values and continue asking if invalid.

**Filling the 2D array**

```
int[][] field = new int[x][y];

for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    System.out.println();
    for(int j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
        char c = binaries[i].charAt(j);
        if(c == '0')
            field[i][j] = 0;
        else
            field[i][j] = 1;

        System.out.print(field[i][j] + " ");
    }
}
```

`Integer.parseInt` is not necessary here as there are only two possible values (0 and 1)